# signup bug - try facebook -> cancel -> try email signup

Tags: bug, facebook, sign-up

When I signed up, I tried using Facebook first and when got prompted with the Facebook greeting that this site will receive access to your email etc, I hit cancel and then entered site signup email and password. After hitting enter, I got sent to the Facebook greeting again. Refreshing the signup page and doing email signup directly worked as expected - after entering email and pass I got the message to wait for the confirmation email.